# Vue trix editor doesn't show the attachments ( image) contents

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-trix

I"m using `vue-trix` npm package in my project, but my attachments(images) aren't showing in the trix-editor, the attachments aren't showing, why is this happening 
I use it like this

```html
 <div class="flex inline-block w-full">
<VueTrix class="editor1 w-full" inputId="editor1" @trix-change="handleEditorChange" @trix-initialize="handleTrixInit" @trix-attachment-remove="handleAttachmentRemove" @trix-attachment-add="handleAttachmentAdd" v-model="form.complete_description" />

     </div>
```

> When I have to edit the entry there

I only get like the file name not the image itself inside the trix editor

[The trix editor that shwos up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inmyr.png)

Here's a fiddle brothers & sister
https://jsfiddle.net/9tLyfo26/

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-newton-yr9vk?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: please add a js fiddle with a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When I save those attachments they're pretty ok, they are stored in storage folder thou

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9tLyfo26/

Comment: Wow seems like you're going to need to trace that src image

Comment: how to do that ?